# Nginx gives 404 for files with the name in Hindi

Tags: nginx, language, languages

I had a WordPress site running on GoDaddy CPanel hosting. The site uses Hindi (the Indian Language). It runs fine with GoDaddy. Once I migrate it to Digital Ocean VPS with PHP 7 and Nginx 1.14.0, a few images give 404 error messages.

After debugging, I found that Nginx shows a 404 error for images which have the name written in the Hindi language; for English names it works fine.

Could anyone let me know what font setting I need to do for Nginx to detect static files with Hindi file names?

Answer (score 1):

The language should work correctly if the option to use the language as a parameter is selected in WPML > Languages. It is advisable to use "The WordPress Multilingual Plugin" which can help in translation.

Please check and let me know if this answers your issue.